# how to get the average response time for a request using Jmeter testing tool

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am trying Jmeter for load and performance test, so I created the thread group and below is the output of aggregate report.

The first column `Avg request t/s`, i have calculated using the formula

```
((Average/Total Requests)/1000)
```

but it does not seems good, as I am loggin request time in my code, almost every request is taking minimum 2-4 seconds.

I tried with `MEdian/1000` but again, i am in doubt.

what is the corerct way to get the average time for a request?

| Avg request t/s | Total Requests | Average | MEdian | Min | Max | Error % | ThroughPut request per time unit | Recieved KB | Sent KB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.07454 | 100 | 7454 | 6663 | 2464 | 19313 | 0 | 3/sec | 2.062251152 | 1.074506499 |
| 1.11322 | 100 | 111322 | 107240 | 4400 | 222042 | 0 | 26.3/min | 0.1408915377 | 0.1271878015 |
| 1.19035 | 100 | 119035 | 117718 |  |  | 0.03 | 26.3/min | 0.1309013211 | 0.1279624502 |
| 1.21287 | 100 | 121287 | 119198 |  |  | 0 | 0.4136384882 | 0.135725129 | 0.1211831508 |
| 1.11943 | 100 | 111943 | 111582 | 5257 | 220004 | 0 | 0.4359482965 | 0.1507086884 | 0.1264420352 |
| 1.14289 | 100 | 114289 | 114215 | 4543 | 223947 | 0 | 0.4369846313 | 0.1497867242 | 0.1288763268 |
| 0.23614 | 150 | 35421 | 26731 | 4759 | 114162 | 0 | 0.9494271789 | 0.3600282257 | 0.1842358496 |

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have the `ThroughPut request per time unit` column already? What else do you need to "calculate"?

As per [Aggregate Report documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)

> Throughput - the [Throughput](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html#Throughput) is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.

So if you click `Save Table Data` button:

[image]

you will get the average transactions per second in the CSV file

It is also possible to generate the CSV file with the calculated aggregate values using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) as

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv aggregate-report.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Comment: If you're talking about Aggregate Report listener - It is basically [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of all Samplers response times (sum of all response times divided by count). See [JMeter Listeners - Part 2: Listeners that Aggregate Data Samples](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-2-listeners-aggregate-data-samples) article for more detailed explanation if needed. For exact formulae check [Calculator](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) class source code

Comment: like for third row in the questtion, 26.3/min that means 26 requests in a minute, and average is per request is 119035/1000 = 119 sec almost 2 min per request.. but this does not see, accurate?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say. If you run the request with 1 user and response time will be 2 minutes you will get 0.5 request per minute. If you run the request with 2 users and response time will be 2 minutes you will get 1 request per minute. If you run the request with 4 users and response time will be 2 minutes you will get 2 requests/minute. Should I continue till 26 requests per minute?

Comment: I know the calculation buddy and no need to repeat (so sweet of you) and thanks for the answer!! and for the  previoud comment i mean ... from the Jmeter response, i am trying to understand the logic, if you can read previous comment again, i am asking/confirming, if 26.3/minute is the throughput that means it can handle 26 requests in a minute.. but if i check avarage that shows 119035 in the third row under average column , so almost 2 minute for a request.. if i compare both results , 26 request per minute, but avg request time is 2 minute.. on this i have a doubt!!